How to align my rotation to the bezier curve tilt in relative space?
Does someone know how to align my rotation to the curve tilt (present in curve edit mode when we enable the curve normal overlay).
I want to do this manipulation while in relative space. It seems really hard to do because while in global scale, the curve normal attribute keeps changing

Here's a blender file
funkynormal.blend
I'm using blender 4.2

@StefLAncien technically your solution solved the title

This behavior is reported as a bug on projects.blender.org.
